# How do I manually change the resolution?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd

Lots of online sources say simply to change the monitor resolution and launch the game and that it will adjust itself. However, this will cause all sorts of annoying issues due to my running two monitors.

Although I know of the ability to run the game on a 2 monitor set up, both monitors have to be the same size and resolution. My monitors are not the same size/resolution. I am running on Windows 10, and running the Steam version of the game (i.e. HD version).

My food counter is hanging somewhere off the left side of my monitor and I do not know how to fix this.

In the past with other games I have known of fixes involving changing game files and the like. As far as i can tell that may be the only way.

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 2):

There are no resolution options for the fullscreen mode. That said, you can modify it in the windowed mode. For an in-game method to change this:

Press Alt+Enter. This switches the game from borderless Fullscreen to Windowed mode. Then resize the window as you would a regular windows program.

Note that while the game has "HD support", little has been changed to make the UI aware of monitors with high DPI. So while you can resize the game window to any resolution smaller than your monitor's this way, you can't 'upscale' many parts of the UI, short of lowering your monitor resolution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial on the [Steam Community](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221380/discussions/0/828935673003315590/) to play the game in a higher definition that the game allows initaly.

I suggest you to read the steps and there is one that can interest you and solve your problem in section **Game window not centered**

> You will have to change the window offset using setXOffset and
>   setYOffset. If you increase the x value, the window will ba moved to
>   the right, if you increase y it will be moved down.

Comment: Adjusting the offset in my situation would simply scoot the other side of the game off onto the other monitor, and would cause a gap between portions of the game window. I will look into the steam community fix and see if that helps.

Comment: The only fix I see within that steam community thread is the one relating to 4k monitors. I am unsure if it will resolve my issue.